# Float does not work in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

The h3 on my website displays perfectly in IE8+, Firefox, Chrome and Safari etc, but in IE7 it displays wrong.

Here is the link: http://lilwaynehq.com/2011/05/18/1-etranjj-i-own-it-feat-lil-wayne

[This is](http://i51.tinypic.com/anndhf.jpg) what it looks like in IE7:

[image]

---

But this is what it looks like in other browsers and what I want it to look like in IE7:

(broken image)

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm missing something in your CSS, but this might resolve the problem

```
.cat-title a {
   clear:none;
}
```

Alternatively, take a look at [this bug in IE7](http://austinmatzko.com/2007/07/25/internet-explorer-7-float-bug/)

Comment: I just tried adding "clear: none;" and "clear: both;" to the .cat-title a, but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem in IE7 :(

Comment: how about changing the width of that anchor to be 50%? or changing it to `display: inline;`

Comment: I just tried both of them changes, and it still does not fix it in IE7.

Comment: this should help you http://austinmatzko.com/2007/07/25/internet-explorer-7-float-bug/

Comment: That's saying about removing a height, but I don't have a height on my container so I don't think it is that problem?